# Which jQuery plugin should be used to fix the IE6 PNG transparency issue?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, png

Is there an IE6/PNG fix that is officially developed by the jQuery team?

If not which of the available plugins should I use?

Comment: Brian, is there a reason that you can't use GIFs instead?

Comment: transparent or partially transparent images with gradients is the usual suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [jquery.pngFix.js](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/).  I don't know if it's officially sanctioned or not, I do know that it works.  I chose it because it was the plugin included with FancyBox, no other reason.

Comment: That plugin ripped my rounded box images (no one was left) my Silverlight (object tag) didn't work anymore and all my images had an red X error on top of them, like broken image. Didn't work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me either; the cursor stopped changing, links with PNG backgrounds stopped working, and images overlapping the PNGs would get cut off.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  All my images got mangled and text disappeared

Answer (score 3):

This [.htc pngfix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) has always worked for me, even in cases where the jquery plugin failed.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. Some people mention jQuery plugins in the comments as well.

[PNG Fix from 24 Ways](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6)

Comment: This one worked the best among all the ones here that I tried, including DD Belated, the jQuery pngFix plugin, and the Helix HTC. With the others, I either had to add an .htaccess rule to make it work, or it stretched or shrunk the image improperly. The thing that might throw you, however, is that you need to create a blank x.gif file in the same folder as this js script, and then edit the script so that the shim points to the relative path from your base URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Guyz, Here is my Fix to this problem**

Download jQuery-Plugin "pngFix" from (http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de)
Great PlugIn By The Way!!!

**--Change these lines like the following:**

```
// this line
jQuery(this).find("img[src$=.png]:visible").each(function() { 
// this line
jQuery(this).find(":visible").each(function(){
// and this line
jQuery(this).find("input[src$=.png]:visible").each(function() {
```

**--Before the end Place this Code**

```
// Store a reference to the original method.
var _show = jQuery.fn.show;

// Overriding Show method.
jQuery.fn.show = function(){
  // Execute the original method.
  _show.apply( this, arguments );
  // Fix Png 
  return $(this).pngFix();
}

//No more problems with hidden images

})(jQuery);

//The End
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, just wanted to toss this one in. I was digging around for it again and it has one specific advantage over the rest: repeatable backgrounds, as well as background-position (the one thats flagged as the  best answer here actually just scales the background image).

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

It's so great. Just drop it in and forget its there. Have yet to see it explode a set of CSS.